# "If it helps you" or "that helps you"

Tags: difference, pronouns

I would like to reply to my friend that I can help him later tomorrow. I’m not sure, how big difference it is between these two sentences.

> I’m free from 8, if **that** helps

or

> I’m free from 8, if **it** helps

I was gonna send the first option, but I’m not sure how big difference does it make?

Comment: I would say "it", and use "that" to refer to something else, such as, er, "You can find the answer in the library, if that helps".

Comment: "that (free time)" = "it"

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of AmE, I would probably say "that" is more common in this situation.